# PHP Rename problem!

Tags: php

I have a problem using php rename function. If I use the following syntax it works fine.

```
<?php
rename("pages/file.php", "pages/xfile.php");
?>
```

but instead if I use this:

```
<?php
$val = '"pages/file.php"';
$rval = '"pages/xfile.php"';
rename($val, $rval);
?>
```

It does not work and gives an error:

```
Warning: rename("pages/file.php","pages/xfile.php") [function.rename]: The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 123) in C:\wamp\www\page_rename.php on line 2
```

Comment: what are the double quotes for? The single quotes are all you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove a set of quotes from the path names.

```
$val = "pages/file.php";
$rval = "pages/xfile.php";
rename($val, $rval);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have too many quotation marks in the second version. Use this:

```
<?php
$val = 'pages/file.php';
$rval = 'pages/xfile.php'; 
rename($val, $rval);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following wrapper for rename (part of a PHP static Utility Class). 
You can also use the wrapper to rename file with a kind of wildcharacters in the filename.

```
/**
* Renames files in a given directory with a form of wildchars.
* @param  string $dir The directory.
* @param  string $src Name of the source to be changed. (i.e. XX)
* @param  string $dst Name of the result                (i.e. YZ)
* @return null | true
* @since 1.0.6.2
*/
public static function rename($dir, $src, $dst) {
  // First check if it is a directory.
  if (! is_dir( $dir ) ) {
     return null;
  }
  // Renames with some kind of wildchars
  if ($handle = opendir($dir) ) {
     while (false !== ( $fileName = readdir($handle) ) ) {
        // Skips the files
        if ($fileName == "." || $fileName == ".." || $fileName == ".DS_Store" ) {
           continue;
        }
        $newName = str_replace($src, $dst, $fileName);
        rename( sprintf("%s/%s", $dir, $fileName),
                sprintf("%s/%s", $dir, $newName ));
     }
     closedir($handle);
  }
  return true;
}
```